# Which is the better way to load data into MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, csv

I have to load the large amount of data into mongodb from CSV.

Can I use mongoimport or should i have to write a code to read the csv and create a JSON object and insert into mongodb?

Which of these approch is better from performance perspective.

Thank you.

Comment: Just keep in mind that json or csv should conform to some format mongoimport understands, not every json will be imported. In other words, if your input file created with smth else than mongoexport, you are likely to have problems, and may end up writing your own code to import/transform additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mongoimport** assumes your input file in some predefined format, i.e. it cannot import *any* json or csv you feed to it (primarely to use with **mongoexport**, more information [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)).
If your input is created with **mongoexport** - there is no reason to use something else.
Otherwise, you may have a need to write code to transfrom original input or import directly into mongo.
Try mongoimport first with your input, then make decision.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will analyse mongo import export further to get to an approch for our envirnoment.

Answer (score 0):

MongoImport is the de-facto standard to import data into MongoDB. There is no point in re-inventing the wheel and write code which reads json\csv\tsv and imports it in an optimal way. Hence without a second though just make use of mongoimport. :)